# Scotch/PT-Scotch graph vertex reordering for minimizing adjacency matrix bandwidth

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, data-partitioning

Although the **Scotch** documentation is pretty clear it lacks examples of using the API. Even using Google for finding other third party documents, examples or tutorials is a dead end.

My problem is the following:
I want to reorder the vertices of a graph with the goal to reduce the adjacency matrix bandwidth using Scotch. Now Scotch has the GPS (Gibbs-Poole-Stockmeyer) algorithm implemented which is one algorithm that can do this type of reordering. But the documentation says:

> This method is mainly used on separators to reduce the number and
>   extent of extra-diagonal blocks.

I used the strategy string "g" to select the GPS algorithm, tried it with different pass values, but the result doesn't come. All I get is a matrix with bandwidth larger than the original.

My question is: 
How can I tell SCOTCH_graphOrder() to do reordering (to reduce bandwidth) on the whole graph?

If you could at least recommend any resources where I might find the answer, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Could you provide links to the documentation you're relying upon, sparse as it may be?